How to implement screen + video recording using RecordRTC in Angular
I have an app where I can record screen and video (from computer's camera) separately. I would like to have a third option: screen + video recording, where you can see the screen and the computer's camera in the right bottom corner, similar to the following picture:

I tried to record screen + video at the same time, but I don't know how to make it work. This is my current code where screen and video recording work separately:
HTML COMPONENT
        <mat-select
          *ngIf="!isVideoRecording"
          value="screen"
          (selectionChange)="onSelectRecordType($event.value)"
        >
          <mat-option value="screen">Screen</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="video">Video</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <video
          #videoElement
          [class.hidden]="!isVideoRecording && !videoBlobUrl"
        >
          <source
            *ngIf="!isVideoRecording && videoBlobUrl"
            [src]="videoBlobUrl"
          />
        </video>

        <div
          class="start-button"
          *ngIf="!isVideoRecording && !videoBlobUrl"
          (click)="startVideoRecording()"
        >
        </div>
        <div
          mat-icon-button
          class="stop-button"
          *ngIf="isVideoRecording && !videoBlobUrl"
          (click)="stopVideoRecording()"
        ></div>

TYPESCRIPT COMPONENT
export class RecordVideoComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('videoElement') videoElement: any;
  video: any;
  isPlaying = false;
  displayControls = true;
  isVideoRecording = false;
  videoRecordedTime: any;
  videoBlobUrl: any;
  videoBlob: any;
  videoName: any;
  videoStream!: MediaStream;
  videoConf = { video: { height: 600, width: 1080 }, audio: true };
  screenConf = {
    video: {
      displaySurface: 'monitor',
      logicalSurface: true,
      cursor: 'always',
    },
  };
  recordType: 'screen' | 'video' | 'both' = 'screen';

  constructor(
    private readonly ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private readonly recordRtcService: RecordRtcService,
    private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    this.recordRtcService.recordingFailed().subscribe(() => {
      this.isVideoRecording = false;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });

    this.recordRtcService.getRecordedTime().subscribe((time: any) => {
      this.videoRecordedTime = time;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });

    this.recordRtcService.getStream().subscribe((stream: any) => {
      this.videoStream = stream;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });

    this.recordRtcService.getRecordedBlob().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.videoBlob = data.blob;
      this.videoName = data.title;
      this.videoBlobUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(data.url);
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
  }

  onSelectRecordType(recordType: 'screen' | 'video' | 'both'): void {
    this.recordType = recordType;
  }

  startVideoRecording(): void {
    if (!this.isVideoRecording) {
      this.video.controls = false;
      this.isVideoRecording = true;

      const conf = this.recordType === 'video' ? this.videoConf : this.screenConf;

      this.recordRtcService
        .startRecording(conf, this.recordType)
        .then((stream: any) => {
          this.video.srcObject = stream;
          this.video.play();
        })
        .catch(function (err: any) {
          console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
        });
    }
  }

  abortVideoRecording(): void {
    if (this.isVideoRecording) {
      this.isVideoRecording = false;
      this.recordRtcService.abortRecording();
      this.video.controls = false;
    }
  }

  stopVideoRecording(): void {
    if (this.isVideoRecording) {
      this.recordRtcService.stopRecording();
      this.video.srcObject = this.videoBlobUrl;
      this.isVideoRecording = false;
      this.video.controls = true;
    }
  }
}

SERVICE
interface RecordedVideoOutput {
  blob: Blob;
  url: string;
  title: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RecordRtcService {
  private startTime: any;
  private _recorded = new Subject<RecordedVideoOutput>();
  private _recordedUrl = new Subject<string>();
  private _recordingFailed = new Subject<string>();
  private _recordingTime = new Subject<string>();
  private _stream = new Subject<MediaStream>();
  private interval: any;
  private recorder: any;
  private stream: any;

  abortRecording(): void {
    this.stopMedia();
  }

  getRecordedBlob(): Observable<RecordedVideoOutput> {
    return this._recorded.asObservable();
  }

  getRecordedUrl(): Observable<string> {
    return this._recordedUrl.asObservable();
  }

  getRecordedTime(): Observable<string> {
    return this._recordingTime.asObservable();
  }

  getStream(): Observable<MediaStream> {
    return this._stream.asObservable();
  }

  recordingFailed(): Observable<string> {
    return this._recordingFailed.asObservable();
  }

  startRecording(
    conf: any,
    recordType: 'screen' | 'video' | 'both'
  ): Promise<any> {
    var browser = <any>navigator;
    if (this.recorder) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    this._recordingTime.next('00:00');

    if (recordType === 'video') {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        browser.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia(conf)
          .then((stream: any) => {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.record();
            resolve(this.stream);
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            this._recordingFailed.next('');
            reject;
          });
      });
    }
    else if (recordType === 'screen') {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        browser.mediaDevices
          .getDisplayMedia(conf)
          .then((stream: any) => {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((mic) => {
              stream.addTrack(mic.getTracks()[0]);
              this.stream = stream;
              this.record();
              resolve(this.stream);
            });
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            this._recordingFailed.next('');
            reject;
          });
      });
    }
  }

  stopRecording(): void {
    if (this.recorder) {
      this.recorder.stopRecording(this.processVideo.bind(this));
    }
  }

  private processVideo(audioVideoWebMURL: string): void {
    const recordedBlob = this.recorder.getBlob();
    this.recorder.getDataURL(function () {});
    const recordedName = encodeURIComponent(
      'video_' + new Date().getTime() + '.webm'
    );
    this._recorded.next({
      blob: recordedBlob,
      url: audioVideoWebMURL,
      title: recordedName,
    });
    this.stopMedia();
  }

  private record(): void {
    this.recorder = new RecordRTC(this.stream, {
      type: 'video',
      mimeType: 'video/webm',
    });
    this.recorder.startRecording();
    this.startTime = moment();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const currentTime = moment();
      const diffTime = moment.duration(currentTime.diff(this.startTime));
      const time =
        this.toString(diffTime.minutes()) +
        ':' +
        this.toString(diffTime.seconds());
      this._recordingTime.next(time);
      this._stream.next(this.stream);
    }, 500);
  }

  private stopMedia(): void {
    if (this.recorder) {
      this.recorder = null;
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.startTime = null;

      if (this.stream) {
        this.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach((track: any) => track.stop());
        this.stream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track: any) => track.stop());
        this.stream.stop();
        this.stream = null;
      }
    }
  }

  private toString(value: any): any {
    let val = value;

    if (!value) {
      val = '00';
    }

    if (value < 10) {
      val = '0' + value;
    }

    return val;
  }
}

